# How to understand certain protein names

Tags: cell-biology, nomenclature

I am looking for a reference to help me understand what is meant by acronyms such as : H3K9me1, H3K9me2, and H3K9Ac.

I know that these are all histone proteins, but is there a general nomenclature algorithm for all cellular proteins? Are H3K9me1 and H3K9me2 just different proteins that methylate the same region? What is meant by H3K? Etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For H3K9me1:

- H3: name of the histone
- K9: amino acid and position (K = lysine, position 9) of modification
- me1: modification (me = methylation, ac = Acetylation), and number of modifications

So H3K9me1 means that the 9th residue (lysine) of [histone H3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histone_H3) was monomethylated. Similarly H3K9Ac means that same residue was acetylated.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histone#Function) gives a decent explanation of the nomenclature of histone modifications, and there is also a more detailed table in [Nature Structural & Molecular Biology](http://www.nature.com/nsmb/journal/v12/n2/fig_tab/nsmb0205-110_T1.html).

Comment: Thanks! This is great, now when we say H3K9me1 vs. H3K9me2, is there a different protein that performs this single vs. double methylation, or can chIp-Seq or western blotting techniques somehow differentiate between when the same protein adds one or two methyl groups?

Comment: @NaiveHalmos I don't know offhand but there are a number of histone methyltransferases (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histone_methyltransferase). It looks like there are a number of methods to differentiate between different modifications, e.g. see http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22130888

Comment: There is also a cool table at [Cell Signaling Technology's website](http://www.cellsignal.com/common/content/content.jsp?id=science-tables-histone) that lists all the known or suspected histone modifications, the modifying enzymes (again, if known), and known or suspected functions.

Comment: @NaiveHalmos if an appropriate reagent is available, yes you can differentiate between mono-, di-, and tri-methylation by Western or ChIP/ChIP-Seq. My lab uses a lot of CST's stuff, so I know they have a bunch of specific antibodies, but I'm sure other vendors do as well.